# View Picker update based on selection in other picker view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have 2 pickers, each has an array with 4 identical items. I want that when I select any value in first picker, it gets removed from the second picker.

I've written a code, but it isn't working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.inWord.delegate = self;

    //Set tags to differentiate
    from.tag=1;
    to.tag=2;

    //Load  NSArray fromlang
    _fromlang= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"English",@"Spanish",@"German",@"Chinese", nil];

    //Load  NSArray tolang
    _tolang= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1English",@"1Spanish",@"German",@"Chinese", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)        // from
    {
        return _fromlang.count;
    }
    else  //if(pickerView.tag==2)                      //to
    {
        return _tolang.count;
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView.tag==1)          //from
    {
        if ([[_fromlang objectAtIndex:row ]  isEqual:@"Spanish"])
        {
            _tolang = @[ @"English",@"DeleteSanish",@"German",@"Chinese"];
        }
        return [_fromlang objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else  //if(pickerView.tag==2)                    //to
    {
        return [_tolang objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

I have tried for one case where if I select Spanish in first picker, it shows deletespanish in the second picker. But I'm getting second picker by default as deletespanish.

Can somebody tell me what is happenning ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` is called when that specific row is displayed. And this happens for all visible rows of your picker.

Selection happens in `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`. And that's where you should manipulate the content of the second picker array. And after you have updated the array that backs the picker you have to call `reloadAllComponents` or `reloadComponent:` for the second picker.